# Elementor CSS files still linked to dev site after moving WordPress site to production domain

Tags: wordpress, element

I recently developed a WordPress site using Elementor on a development domain. After completing the development, I moved the site to the production domain. However, I noticed that some Elementor CSS files are still linked to the development domain.

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

- Clearing browser cache.
- Checking and updating the WordPress Site URL and Home settings.
- Searching the database for instances of the old domain and updating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to clear the elementor cache in your wordpress. you can go to Elementor > Tools > Regenerate CSS & Data. Click on Regenerate Files & Data and hit Save Changes